# Elasticsearch 2.1 - Deprecated search types

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

According to this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/breaking_21_search_changes.html), both `scan` and `count` are deprecated.

I am trying to change my queries to reflect this. So the `count` change is easy, just removing the search type and adding `size=0` to the request, however, I am not 100% on the `scan` change.

Currently I have this query:

```
var result = ElasticClient.Search<Product>(s => s
    .From(0)
    .Size(10)
    .SearchType(SearchType.Scan)
    .Scroll("4s")
    .Query
        (qu =>
            qu.Filtered
                (fil =>
                    fil.Filter
                        (f =>
                            f.Bool(b => b.Must(m => m.Term("filedName", "abc")))))));
```

Am I correct in my understanding that all I need to change is remove the `searchtype` and add a `sort`? I.e:

```
var result = ElasticClient.Search<Product>(s => s
    .From(0)
    .Size(10)
    .Scroll("4s")
    .Sort(x => x.OnField("_doc"))
    .Query
        (qu =>
            qu.Filtered
                (fil =>
                    fil.Filter
                        (f => f.Bool(b => b.Must(m => m.Term("filedName", "abc")))))));
```

I have seen a enum `SortSpecialField` [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/82c938893b2ff4ddca03a8e977ad14a16da712ba/src/Nest/Search/Search/Sort/SortSpecialField.cs), but I am not sure how to actually use this in the `sort` parameter.

Comment: Which version of NEST are you using?

Comment: From nuget, elasticsearch.net and nest.... both 1.7.1

Comment: NEST and Elasticsearch.NET 1.7.1 are not compatible with ES 2.x - they may generally work but there are changes in Elasticsearch that will not e.g. error responses. There is a 2.x alpha pre-release of NEST on nuget

Comment: hmm yes, [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/releases)  6 days ago. totally missed it. Hmm ok. My understanding but of the syntax/logic change to the query is correct but right? I mean, I just need to add the 'sort' on the doc field and the query will work the same....

Comment: Yes, the change you have outlined above looks correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're correct in your understanding that the change (as you document in your question) to sort by `_doc` will replace the deprecated `Scan` searchtype. The `SortSpecialField` enum is just syntax sugar for sorting by `_doc`. If you prefer to use it, in NEST 2.0 [only], you can do this:

```
ElasticClient.Search<Product>(s => s
.From(0)
.Size(10)
.Scroll("4s")
.Sort(x => x.Ascending(SortSpecialField.DocumentIndexOrder))
    ...
```